# how to remove the subdomain from external video links only

Tags: php, hyperlink, external, subdomain

We have info being inputted on the subdomain (`www.agent.xxxx.com`) and posting results from the editor on the main site (`www.xxxx.com`) everything from the editor is displayed correct except for external video links. Using the code here the results for video links are adding the subdomain agent/ in front of the link causing the error and resulting in `agent/www.youtube.com/xxxxxx`

We just need to correct this only on external links

```
<?php
    $this->result->aboutme = str_replace('src="', c="agents/', $this->result->aboutme);     
    echo $this->result->aboutme;
?>
```

Comment: Do your external links have "http://" on the beginning? If so, it makes it easier to spot them with a regex.

Comment: what is this: c="agents/' supposed to do ?

Comment: c="agents/' is used to display results of fields used in the sub-domain agent.www.xxx.com on the main site www.xxx.com All info is coming from the editor (aboutme) and is displayed in the main site

Comment: My external links (youtube) that are placed in the sub-domains editor using the embed media option are being broken as the current code is causing the /agent/ to be place in front of the url (/agents/http://www.youtube.com/embed/IIIw3UMKdf4) this is causing link error

Comment: <?php
            $this->result->aboutme = str_replace('src="images', 'src="/agents/images', $this->result->aboutme);     
            echo $this->result->aboutme;
            ?>